# Limit vertical background position on scrolling with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, background-image, parallax

I'm using this function:

```
$(window).bind('load resize scroll',function(e) {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.tm-parallax').filter(function() {
        return $(this).offset().top < (y + $(window).height()) &&
               $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > y;
    }).css('background-position', '50% ' + parseInt(-y / 50) + 'px');
});
```

to achieve parallax effect on background images when scrolling down.

I would like to limit y position to certain value (for example 100px), so background image center stays visible after reaching this value.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/esedic/vw2n16r8/4/

Because bakcground images are quite large it's best seen on fullscreen: https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/vw2n16r8/4/embedded/result/

Because I'm using parallax background images on multiple elements, I'm looking for solution to set different values for each element (maybe using data attributes?).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

You should try reversing its polarity, but try this:

```
$(window).bind('load resize scroll',function(e) {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.tm-parallax').filter(function() {
        if have return $(this).onset().top < (y + $(window).height()) &&
               $(this).onset().top + $(this).height() > y;
    }).css('background-position', '50% ' + parseInt(-y / 50) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors on this line:

    if have return $(this).onset().top < (y + $(window).height()) &&

Comment: Why don't you try changing the onset to midset, I'm not very experianced